# Existence of a global involution extension.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, differential-topology, dynamical-systems, germs

I'm studying the paper "Local and simultaneous structural stability of certain diffeomorphisms. - Marco Antonio Teixeira". At the beginning of the paper, the author gives the following definition
[image]

Besides that, the author states the following lemma:
[image: ![enter image description here]

However, he does not demonstrate such a result, just saying "the lemma is easy to proof".

I know how to find an extension $\omega:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ of  $\left. \varphi \right|_{U}$ such that $\varphi'(0) + \beta$ where $\beta \in \mathcal C_b^0 (\mathbb{R}^2)$ is Lipschitz with bounded constant by $\varepsilon$. However, I don't have the faintest idea how to guarantee $\omega\circ \omega= \mathrm{Id}.$

Can anyone help me?

---

### How do I constructed the function $\omega$

Define $F= \varphi$ and $L = \mathrm{d} \varphi(0)$.

First, choose a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ real function $\beta:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying:

- $\beta(x) = 0 $, $\forall$ $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R} \setminus [-1,1]$.
- $\beta(x) =1$, $\forall$ $x$ $\in$ $ \left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right].$
- $\beta (x)$ is a increasing function in $\left[-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right]$ and $\beta(x)$ is a decreasing function in $\left[\frac{1}{2}, 1\right]$.

Note that,  $\beta$ is compact support $\mathcal{C}^\infty$, so, there exists  $M$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$, such that, $M = \sup \{|D\beta(x)|; \hspace{0.1cm} x \in \mathbb{R}\} $.

We define $\phi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ as  $\phi(x) = F(x) - Lx$. Observe that the function $\phi$ is a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$, moreover, $D\phi(0) = 0$. Therefore, for the real number $\widetilde{\varepsilon} = \min\left\{ \frac{\varepsilon}{2M} , \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right\} > 0$ there exists $1 \geq r >0$ such that
$$x \in B_r (0) \subset U \Rightarrow \Vert D\phi(x) \Vert < \widetilde{\varepsilon} $$
implying, by the mean value theoream that, if $x \in B_r (0)  \Rightarrow \Vert \phi(x) \Vert < \widetilde{\varepsilon}\Vert x\Vert $.

Now, consider $\omega: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined as:
$$\omega(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{l}
 Lx + \beta\left(\frac{\Vert x \Vert}{r}\right)\phi(x), \hspace{0.1cm} \text{if} \hspace{0.1cm} x \in U,\\ 
    Lx, \hspace{0.1cm} \text{if} \hspace{0.1cm} x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus U. \end{array} \right. $$

Thus, defining $r_1 = r$ and $r_2 = \frac{r}{2}$. It is easy to verify that

- $\omega = F$ in $B_{r_2} (0)$.
- $\omega = L$ outside $B_{r_1}(0)$.
- The function $\alpha = G - L$ is bounded by $\varepsilon$.
- $\alpha$  is $\varepsilon$-Lipschitz.

Once $\omega = L +\alpha$, we constructed such an extension. However, $\omega \circ \omega $ is not necessarily equal to $\mathrm{Id}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a proof of this statement in the paper "Simultaneous linearization of a class of pairs of involutions with normally hyperbolic composition - Marco Antonio Teixeira, Solange Mancini, Miriam Manoel".

I made some edits in the image below since the content that answers my question is just a part of the proof of Lemma $4.2$. I have erased all the information that is not related to the problem that I wanted to solve.

[image]